# How to connect database is running inside the container container from outside?

Tags: postgresql, docker-compose, dockerfile, python-docker

I have created postgres docker image using `docker-compose up` command.
`docker-compose` up command is also installing some python packages like `poetry ,python3,pip etc.` once container is up we are executing `docker exec container_name poetry run pytest` command to run test cases. Tests running fine on local but on the server it is giving below error. Any quick fix around this issue?

> connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: Cannot assign requested address Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?

Comment: Use the [ports](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/05-services/#ports) parameter in your configuration file to expose port 5432 to connections outside the container.

Comment: @Alex Howansky- already used 
 ports:
      - "5432:5432"